is there an actual acoustic difference between diphthongs and V+semivowels/approximant/glide sequences?
I'm working on a phonological sketch of a minority language, and although I know the basics of phonology, I'm not much of a phonologist phonetician.
In the language, there are syllables that would appear to be contain syllables that can be described as such:
/tia/ -or- /tja/ (complex onset)
/au/ -or- /aw/
published descriptions of related languages heavily dis-prefer the diphthong analysis, however, as far as I can tell, this seems to be a convention that gets cited and repeated and no source that I have yet found provides any phonological/phonetic evidence one way or the other
My question here is whether it's possible to just open some examples in praat determine acoustically whether something is or isn't a diphthong,
or in other words, is there an actual acoustic difference between a diphthong like /au/ and a V+approximant sequence like /aw/? Or are these these different conventional approaches to the same phenomena?

No - if it were possible to determine acoustically, there would be no cases where both analyses are found in the literature, but a lot of languages have this variation (including English).
One relevant question could be - if one proposes the existence of /j w/ in the language's phonemic inventory, are there minimal pairs with /i u/? Like /ji wu/ vs /i u/ (which could be realized as vowel length)? If not, then the analysis with /i u/ and no glides in the phonemic inventory may seem more parsimonious in the absence of further evidence to the contrary.
